# Rails encrypt Database password in database.yml for SQL-Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, configuration

Our server departement demands to encrypt passwords in all Rails applications.
Is there a way to encrypt the password in database.yml for MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Crypto gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/crypto) for that

`encrypted_password = Crypto.encrypt(password, 128_character_key, 128_character_iv)`

To decrypt use

```
password = Crypto.decrypt(encrypted_password,same_key,same_iv)
```

Comment: Good SO answer should include more than just a link.